# What is a typical JavaScript code coverage for LWCs (Lightning Web Components) that are adequately tested via JEST?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, code-coverage, lwc-jest

I know this might get closed as being a matter of opinion, but as long as those opinions are *based on actual experience*, such answers are valuable to me, particularly if they are somewhat consistent.

For Apex code, I expect to get 90% code coverage by writing tests that assert the functionality of the logic. (IMHO, to get to 100% requires "busy" work that adds little value and can couple the tests to implementation detail.)

What JavaScript code coverage to you get working on LWCs that have good JEST tests?

**PS**

Just looked at one set of 100 or so LWCs and they are at about 70%. But the more involved ones - co-ordinating user interactions - typically have lower coverage.

Comment: Our core product LWCs (23 of them) have 361 tests between them with average coverage of 88% - lowest a shocking 29% and highest being 100%.